# Reader-writers problem using semaphores in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, producer-consumer

I have written my own solution to the Reader-Writers problems using semaphores based on the [psuedocode from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writers_problem).  I would like to gauge the correctness and quality of the code.

```
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

class ReaderWritersProblem {

    static Semaphore readLock = new Semaphore(1);
    static Semaphore writeLock = new Semaphore(1);
    static int readCount = 0;

    static class Read implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                //Acquire Section
                readLock.acquire();
                readCount++;
                if (readCount == 1) {
                    writeLock.acquire();
                }
                readLock.release();

                //Reading section
                System.out.println("Thread "+Thread.currentThread().getName() + " is READING");
                Thread.sleep(1500);
                System.out.println("Thread "+Thread.currentThread().getName() + " has FINISHED READING");

                //Releasing section
                readLock.acquire();
                readCount--;
                if(readCount == 0) {
                    writeLock.release();
                }
                readLock.release();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    static class Write implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                writeLock.acquire();
                System.out.println("Thread "+Thread.currentThread().getName() + " is WRITING");
                Thread.sleep(2500);
                System.out.println("Thread "+Thread.currentThread().getName() + " has finished WRITING");
                writeLock.release();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Read read = new Read();
        Write write = new Write();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(read);
        t1.setName("thread1");
        Thread t2 = new Thread(read);
        t2.setName("thread2");
        Thread t3 = new Thread(write);
        t3.setName("thread3");
        Thread t4 = new Thread(read);
        t4.setName("thread4");
        t1.start();
        t3.start();
        t2.start();
        t4.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't have the reputation to comment, but wanted to note that the above code submitted by OP can result in writer starvation. See the "Second Readers-Writers Problem" section [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writers_problem#second-readers-writers-problem) for adjustments that alleviate the writer starvation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic looks good in this program, but I am observing that there is a problem with `readCount`. Suppose if two threads (say `t1` and `t2`) reach `readCount++` at the same time. Initially, both will read the `readCount` value to be 0, and after being incremented by both, the value will be corrupted i.e., it may be 2 and the same will happen with `readCount--`.

The problem is that, according to the Java memory model, if this read and write for `readCount` are not atomic, we can declare the `readCount` as `volatile`:

```
volatile static int readCount = 0;
```

**Will `volatile` resolve the problem:**

Again, by declaring the `readCount` as `volatile`, it now makes the read and write operations atomic, meaning that every thread will read the updated value of `readCount` as there will be no optimizations by the compiler (as `volatile` declared). There will be only one copy of the variable and that will be in main memory, so every thread will read/write the value in main memory only. Now there will no variable copies in thread caches.

But still, this is not the full-proof solution, because increment/decrement operations on any variable are not atomic operations. `readCount++` (or `readCount--`) is not a single operation and consists of these three operations:

1. Read `readCount`
2. Add one to `readCount`, i.e. `readCount` + 1, (`readCount` - 1, in case of `readCount--`)
3. Write the value (from step 2) again in `readCount`

**Note**: There are lots of links on Google about `volatile`, such as [this one](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/volatile.html).

In order to solve this problem, I can think of two approaches:

1. **`synchronized` block**

   We can write both increment (`readCount++`) and decrement (`readCount--`) operations in a `synchronized` block, because `readCount` is `static`. Will use a `ReaderWritersProblem.class` object for the `synchronized` block. Now, any thread that wants to enter the block first has to acquire the lock on the `ReaderWritersProblem.class` object. Then only it can proceed, otherwise it will wait. This way, we can make the increment/decrement operations atomic (which is actually composed of three operations, explained as above):

   Replace `readCount++`:

   ```
   synchronized(ReaderWritersProblem.class) {
       readCount++;
   }
   ```

   Replace `readCount--`:

   ```
   synchronized(ReaderWritersProblem.class) {
       readCount--;
   }
   ```
2. **`AtomicInteger` class**

   We can use Java in-built atomic concurrent APIs i.e. classes in package `java.util.concurrent.atomic`. As `readCount` is of type `Integer`, we can go for an `AtomicInteger` class. This class provides methods for increment and decrement operations and guarantees the atomicity of these operations.

   We can modify the code as such:

   Replace the `readCount` declaration:

   ```
   static AtomicInteger readCount = new AtomicInteger(0);
   ```

   Replace `readCount++`:

   ```
   readCount.getAndIncrement();
   ```

   Replace `readCount--`:

   ```
   readCount.getAndDecrement();
   ```

   You can check [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) for more APIs in the `AtomicInteger` class.

Comment: This is incorrect. `readCount++` and `readCount--` are protected by locks in critical sections, so there's no chance of multiple threads modifying the variables simultaneously.

Answer (score 3):

The `readLock` semaphore protects the `readCount` variable, so the original code is fine. No need for additional mechanisms to make it atomic in this case.

Answer (score 3):

There's no need to use `synchronize` for readers, as you are acquiring the lock for `readCount++` and `readCount--`.

One drawback in your code is the **[starvation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starvation_(computer_science))** for writers. The first reader has acquired `writeLock`, and so subsequent readers will keep on coming and will not let `readCount` become 0. So any waiting writers will always wait for `writeLock` to be released and will eventually starve.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest declaring your semaphores as fair:

```
static Semaphore readLock = new Semaphore(1, true);
static Semaphore writeLock = new Semaphore(1, true);
```

With that, the threads are placed into a FIFO queue when blocked, so any starvation problems are solved.

BTW, I've added a new version [in this post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/216603/java-many-readers-one-writer-with-semaphores-and-multithreading)

Comment: I don't see how semaphores solves starvation of writers when there's an endless supply of readers. This isn't much of a substantial review, mostly a link to another post.